# "Script as a render blocking file" after using Web Font Loader

Tags: javascript, fonts, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, webfont-loader

I am trying to remove the "Script as render blocking file" error from [Google Pagespeed insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) caused by loading a Google web font. The internet tells me to use [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to load the fonts async. I placed the following piece of javascript in my footer, the font loads well, but I still get the Render blocking error in my pagespeed insights results.

Note: The Font Render blocking error only shows up at the mobile test, not on desktop.

```
<script>
      WebFontConfig = {
         google: {
            families: ['Archivo Narrow:300,400,700']
         }
      };

      (function(d) {
         var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
         wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
         wf.async = true;
         s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(document);
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Tried to add the script before closing body tag will still cause an render blocking file error:

```
<script>
   WebFontConfig = {
      google: {
         families: ['Archivo Narrow:300,400,700']
      }
   };

   (function(d) {
      var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
      wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
      wf.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(wf);
   })(document);
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Where in the html document is this script block? You might just have to move it to the bottom of the body.

Comment: @Shilly The script created by this piece of code is placed in the <head>. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Try placing it at the bottom of the body. It's a font, so it would make sense to have it near the style sheets in the head, but if the browser complains that its blocking rendering, this might be a solution.

Comment: Thats fine as long as your Async code is in the Footer as I would expect the script tag would be embed itself in the Head, as your code is adds the external script before the ParentNode of the first Script

Comment: @Shilly I have tried to insert it before the closing body tag, but still get the error. (check my edit)

Comment: You've certainly set your script to load asynchronously correctly using the optimised async flag for HTML5 compatible browsers and the classic script embed fallback for non-HTML5 browser, so other than Deferring the loading(Which would be bad for a Web font). I can't see why this would be render blocking

Comment: Because the script is loaded asynchronously its almost irrelevant where the script is appended

Comment: Try adding your Async script code to an empty HTML file, I'm sure you'll find passes it will pass PageSpeeds tests which will prove its something else on your page

Comment: Robert, I'm seeing the same issue, the webfont is mentioned as one of the reasons for the PSI to fail on the render blocking test. Have you made any progress on it?